# Get height of the retina screen using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

As specified in http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/galaxy-tab/SM-T700NZWAXAR

Resolution of the Samsung tab 8.4 is 1600 x 2560 Pixels, 360ppi, however when I try to get the height with JQUERY using `$(window).height()` , it returns 1280.

Resolution of the Samsung S3 i9300 is 720×1280, 306ppi, but when I try to get the height with JQUERY using `$(window).height()` , it returns the correct value of 1280.

`window.devicePixelRatio =2` for both devices.

Why does the Samsung tab 8.4 return half of the original value?

How do I get it to return the correct height?

Are there any other factors I need to consider as it is a retina display?

Comment: Samsung does not use *Retina Display* in their products.

Comment: The physical number of pixels of the device is not necessarily the logical number used for display. High resolution displays may use 4 physical pixels (i.e. a 2x2 block) for each logical pixel. What most applications want to know is the logical pixels, not physical pixels (which is usually 1:1 for common displays but not for high–resolution or scaled displays).

Comment: 1600 x 2560 is this is physical pixels?